# Freeing programmatically modified UIImage throws exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, automatic-ref-counting, calloc

I have programmed an image filter which generates a new UIImage from the old one pixel by pixel. In the class that contains my image the declaration is as follows:

```
@property   UIImage *imageHandle;       // contains the image of the class
```

My filter in my CBImage class extracts the bitmap as a char array (pixels) from the UIImage, allocates a new char array buffer (newPixels) with the same size and then runs through the RGBA pixels to reconstruct the filtered image in newPixels. Finally it generates a new UIImage and returns this.

This is the code (CBImage is my class which contains the declaration as above):

```
-(CBImage *)doMyFancyStuff
{
// set up some convenience variables
UIImage *image = self.imageHandle;
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
NSData *imageData = (NSData *)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef)));
NSLog(@"NumPixels %d", [imageData length]);
char *pixels = (char *)[imageData bytes];

char *newPixels = (char *)calloc([imageData length], sizeof(char));

// run through the image and manipulate the image
for (NSInteger i=0; i< [imageData length]; i+=4)
{
    if ([whatEverIWantIsTrueForMyFilter])
    {
        // color pixel white and ALPHA = 1.0
        newPixels[i] = 255;
        newPixels[i+1] = 255;
        newPixels[i+2] = 255;
        newPixels[i+3] = 255;
    }
    else
        newPixels[i+3] = 0;  // make pixel translucent
}

// create new image
CBImage *result = [[CBImage alloc] init];

// construct new UImage 
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
size_t bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);
size_t bitsPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);
size_t bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);

CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, newPixels, [imageData length], NULL);

CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorspace, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, FALSE, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

result.imageHandle = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

// clean up
free(pixels);
free(newPixels);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
newImageRef = Nil;

return result;
```

}

All this seems to work nicely and I can display the newly created UImage in my view controller:

```
CBImage *overlayImage = [testCBImage doMyFancyStuff];
self.overlayView.image = overlayImage.imageHandle;
```

But...a BAD_ACCESS exception is thrown if I want to release the image again:

```
self.overlayView.image = Nil;
```

I don't know what's wrong here. The only suspicion I have is the calloc call in line #10 in my filter method above because I sort of "manually" allocate memory (although I release it again at the end of the method), which is then not referenced any more when the UIImage handle is set to Nil...but I'm not sure.

I am using iOS7 and ARC.

Any ideas?

Beschi

Comment: Change this: `@property   UIImage *imageHandle;` to: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *imageHandle;`.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *pixels = (char *)[imageData bytes];
```

And then, later on ...

```
free(pixels);
```

However, pixels was not created using a create / malloc / ... etc., and does not need to be released.

Also, consider having the property declared with retain (or strong, same stuff).

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)UIImage *imageHandle;       // contains the image of the class
```

Comment: Thanks...realized that. But even commenting this out does not help. The exception is NOT thrown in the filter method, but in the view controller when the UIImage using the "newPixels" bitmap is released.